# Proof in First-Order Logic using Compactness Theorem

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If we have $\Sigma$ and $T$ as two first-order theories such they do not have any common models.

How can I prove that there is a sentence φ such that Σ ⊨ φ and Τ ⊨ ¬ φ? Does Compactness Theorem help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HINT: Suppose that there is no such sentence. Let $\Phi$ be any finite subset of $\Sigma$, and let $\varphi=\bigwedge\Phi$; clearly $\Sigma\vDash\varphi$. Now show that there is a model of $T\cup\Phi$, and use the compactness theorem to get a common model.

Comment: Thanks @Brian! I was using the same approach, but cannot show that there is a model for $T\cup\Phi$, because we know virtually nothing about $T$... Any insights on that?

Comment: @Bill: You don’t need to know anything about $T$ beyond the fact that by hypothesis it’s *not* true that $T\vDash\neg\varphi$.

Comment: That's right, but what if $T$ itself has no model at all? I'm kind of confused...

Comment: @Bill: If $T$ is inconsistent, then $T\vDash\psi$ is vacuously true for any $\psi$, so you immediately get a $\psi$ such that $\Sigma\vDash\psi$ and $T\vDash\neg\psi$. Thus, you may as well assume that $T$ has a model.

Comment: But in this case we still don't know anything about the relation between $T$ and $\phi$ right? Is there some sort of an extension theorem that allows us to extend from model of $T$ to $T\cup\phi$?

Comment: Sorry if my questions sound stupid, but I'm really new this area...

Comment: @Bill: You’re not using your hypothesis! We’re assuming that there is no sentence $\varphi$ such that $\Sigma\vDash\varphi$ and $T\vDash\neg\varphi$. That means that if you have a sentence such that $\Sigma\vDash\varphi$, then you know that it’s not true that $T\vDash\neg\varphi$ and hence (assuming that $T$ is consistent) that $T\cup\{\varphi\}$ is consistent, i.e., that it has a model.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18594/discussion-between-bill-liu-and-brian-m-scott).